# update if row with some unique value exists, else insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers, plpgsql

I have a URLs table. They contain

(id int primary key,
 url character varying unique, 
content character varying, 
last analyzed date).

I want to create trigger or something(rule may be), so each time i make insert from my java program, it updates some single row if row with such URL exists. Else it should perform an Insert.

Please, can you provide a complete code in Postgresql. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [POSTGRESQL INSERT if specific row name don't exists !](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297045/postgresql-insert-if-specific-row-name-dont-exists)

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This has been asked many times. A possible solution can be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527838/552671

This solution requires both an `UPDATE` and `INSERT`.

```
UPDATE table SET field='C', field2='Z' WHERE id=3;
INSERT INTO table (id, field, field2)
       SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE id=3);
```

With Postgres 9.1 it is possible to do it with one query:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1109198/2873507

Comment: `SELECT 3, 'C', 'Z'` How are you able to select via row value instead of column name?

Comment: @insivika that line is part of the INSERT statement, he's specifying the column name in the previous line.

Answer (score 16):

If `INSERTS` are rare, I would avoid doing a `NOT EXISTS (...)` since it emits a `SELECT` on all updates. Instead, take a look at wildpeaks answer: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/5815/how-can-i-insert-if-key-not-exist-with-postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION upsert_tableName(arg1 type, arg2 type) RETURNS VOID AS $$ 
    DECLARE 
    BEGIN 
        UPDATE tableName SET col1 = value WHERE colX = arg1 and colY = arg2; 
        IF NOT FOUND THEN 
        INSERT INTO tableName values (value, arg1, arg2); 
        END IF; 
    END; 
    $$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This way Postgres will initially try to do a `UPDATE`. If no rows was affected, it will fall back to emitting an `INSERT`.

Answer (score 9):

I found [this post](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/sql/upsert/) more relevant in this scenario:

```
WITH upsert AS (
     UPDATE spider_count SET tally=tally+1 
     WHERE date='today' AND spider='Googlebot' 
     RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO spider_count (spider, tally) 
SELECT 'Googlebot', 1 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM upsert)
```

Answer (score 7):

Firstly It tries insert. If there is a conflict on *`url`* column then it updates content and last_analyzed fields. If updates are rare this might be better option.

```
INSERT INTO URLs (url, content, last_analyzed)
VALUES
    (
        %(url)s,
        %(content)s,
        NOW()
    ) 
ON CONFLICT (url) 
DO
UPDATE
SET content=%(content)s, last_analyzed = NOW();
```

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.5+ only

Answer (score 2):

```
create table urls (
      url_id serial primary key, 
      url text unique, 
      content text,
      last_analyzed timestamptz);

insert into urls(url) values('hello'),
   ('How'),('are'),
   ('you'),('doing');
```

By creating procedure, you also also do upsert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE upsert_url(_url text) LANGUAGE plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN 
     INSERT INTO URLs (url) values (_url)
      ON CONFLICT (url) 
      DO UPDATE SET last_analyzed = NOW();
END 
$$;
```

Test it through call the procedure.

```
call upsert_url('I am is ok');
call upsert_url('hello');
```