# Ambiguous column reference in INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

Tags: sql, postgresql, upsert

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test."TestCounter" 
("id" TEXT PRIMARY KEY, 
 "count" INTEGER);
```

I'd like to insert a record and increment the counter if the record already exists

```sql
INSERT INTO test."TestCounter" ("id")
VALUES ('id-0')
 ON CONFLICT ("id") DO UPDATE
 SET "count" = ("count" + 1)
 RETURNING "count"
```

Currently I get this error:

```
ERROR:  column reference "count" is ambiguous
LINE 4:  SET "count" = "count" + 1
                       ^
SQL state: 42702
Character: 107
```

Comment: Try Replace into

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan: There is no "Replace Into" in Postgres (or standard SQL).

Comment: Oh my bad. Please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135501/postgresql-update-if-row-with-some-unique-value-exists-else-insert/11135767

Comment: @BeshambherChaukhwan: A trigger won't solve this problem either and is no need for, see the answer below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql column reference "id" is ambiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821121/postgresql-column-reference-id-is-ambiguous)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to table-qualify the column where it would be otherwise ambiguous.
Use the virtual table name `excluded` to refer to the input row. But you probably want to refer to the target column, so qualify with the name of the target table:

```
INSERT INTO test.test_counter (id)
VALUES ('id-0')
ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE
SET count = test_counter.count + 1  -- here
RETURNING count;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

> Note that the special `excluded` table is used to reference values originally proposed for insertion.

The single row from the virtual input table `excluded` contains *all* columns of the target table, even if not listed in the target column list of the `INSERT` or the `VALUES` expression. So the ambiguity you encountered is always there, whether `count` is targeted explicitly or not.

Aside: Columns omitted in the target column list default to their respective column `DEFAULT` value, which is `NULL` by default (`NULL` being the default column `DEFAULT`). I.e., it would default to `NULL` in your setup and `1` in my improved setup below. And row-level triggers `BEFORE INSERT` (if any) are applied.

But neither of that applies  for the example as it refers to the *target* column after all.

Notably, the other two instances of the column name `count` are unambiguous (and thus do not require table-qualification) as those can only refer to the *target* table.

Your setup can easily break while the column `count` isn't defined `NOT NULL`, as `NULL + 1` is still `NULL`. This setup would make more sense:

```
CREATE TABLE test.test_counter (
  id    text PRIMARY KEY
, count integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 1
);
```

Also not using quoted CaMeL-case names in my example. See:

- [Are PostgreSQL column names case-sensitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20878932/are-postgresql-column-names-case-sensitive/20880247#20880247)